# Change font chemfig on LaTeX

Tags: chemfig

Is it possible to change the font that `chemfig` uses (for example to Helvetica) without using `XeLaTeX` or `LuaTeX`, but keep the normal math font throughout the document?

I tried `\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}` and redefining `\printatom` as `\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}` but of course all the math text in the document switches to the Helvetica font (as expected):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Text text text
    \chemfig{-CO_2H}
    More text, and the following equation should use the normal math font $E = mc^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164806/121799) helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by @marmot I eventually did the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\def\Hv@scale{.95}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\foo}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\foo{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Text text text\\

    \chemfig{-CO_2H}\\

    More text, and the following equation should use the normal math font $E = mc^2$. Serif in math works with the default font as well $\mathsf{CO_2H}$.
\end{document}
```

Which is the desired output. I am not sure if there are situations where it may not work as I honestly have no idea what `\DeclareMathAlphabet` does, but it works so far. Any comments, suggestions, correct answers based on this, or explanations as to how is it that this works well are appreciated.

Output:
[image]

Comment: If `chemname` is used the _name_ uses the normal math font.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I switched for `\chemname{\chemfig{-CO_2H}}{test}` in the code above and "test" shows up in normal *text* font, as expected.

Comment: I would like the molecule name show up in helvetica font instead normal font. @ralk912

Comment: Ah, well that's a different question. To do it globally I think you can create a command based on `chemname` that switches the font as suggested in the answer that was linked to. If you ask the question I can post the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @ralk912 answer and [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) I did the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\def\Hv@scale{0.90}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\foo}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\foo{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textHv}{\myfont}

\begin{document}

    Text in the default font. \textHv{Text in the new font.} Again text in the default font.\\

    \chemname{\chemfig{H_3C-CO_2H}}{acetic acid}\quad
    \chemname{\chemfig{H_3C-CO_2H}}{\textHv{acetic acid}}

    \bigskip

    Normal math font: $E = mc^2$. Serif in math with default font: $\mathsf{E = mc^2}$.
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I think you should ask your own question, as this is different than what I was asking

Comment: Based on your answer, I found a solution a few seconds before your comment. Thanks!

Comment: You can also define `\DeclareRobustCommand{\mychemname}[2]{\chemname{#1}{\textHv{#2}}}` and then use `\mychemname` instead of `\chemname`.